# Java coursework questions

Tags: java

I'm an undergraduate student and I'm looking for help with troubleshooting the code I'm writing for my coursework.

```
import weather.WeatherData;
import Weather.data.classes.WeatherReading;
import Weather.data.classes.WeatherStation;

/**
 * QUESTION 01
 * 
 * If you decide to answer question 01 then the main method below should be used as the entry point for your application
 * You may use as many other classes as you feel necessary as long as all code is supplied 
 * 
 * Remember to add -Xmx1024m to the VM arguments using menu run --> run configurations in eclipse
 */
public class Answer01 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Question 01");
        /*
         * Add your code below
         */
        WeatherStation x = new WeatherStation("site", "a", 1.1, 1.0);
        WeatherReading y = new WeatherReading(1,2,3,4,5,6);
        String line[] = WeatherData.getData();
        ArrayList<WeatherStation>weatherSize = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 1; i < line.length; i++){
        String [] split = line[i].split(",");
        WeatherStation z = new WeatherStation(line[0], line[1], Double.parseDouble(line[2]), Double.parseDouble(line[3]));
        weatherSize.add(z);
        }

        System.out.println(weatherSize.size() + " test");

    }   
}
```

The problem I'm having here is that `weatherSize.size()` is printing out `0` instead of the correct answer which is `136`.

The code draws data from a JAR file called `weather.WeatherData` and I created two classes which have getters and setters and `toString()` methods, called `WeatherStation` and `WeatherReading`.

The jar file is library item called WeatherData.jar and it records weather data recorded at different locations in the uk.

String[] weatherData = WeatherData.getData();

Returns an array of string and the first element at index 0 contains header information.

Element 0: SiteId,SiteName,Latitude,Longitude,Year,Month,Date,Hour,WindSpeed,Temperature
Element 1: 
3002,BALTASOUND (3002),60.7490,-0.8540,2015,01,01,0,21,8.70

When I run my code for `Answer01` it simply says: 0 test

```
    package Weather.data.classes;

    public class WeatherStation {
    public String siteId;
    public String siteName;
    public double latitude;
    public double longitude;

    public WeatherStation(String siteId, String siteName, double latitude, double longitute){
        super();
        this.siteId = siteId;
        this.siteName = siteName;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        } 
    }
```

And `WeatherReading`:

```
package Weather.data.classes;

public class WeatherReading {
    public int year;
    public int month;
    public int date;
    public int hour;
    public int windSpeed;
    public int temperature;

    public WeatherReading(int year, int month, int date, int hour, int windSpeed, int temperature){
        this.year = year;
        this.month = month;
        this.date = date;
        this.hour = hour;
        this.windSpeed = windSpeed;
        this.temperature = temperature;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Can you pare down the example a *little* bit and provide sample data to try?

Comment: Why are you doing this: `String [] split = line[i].split(",")`? Where are you using `split`?

Comment: @JacobBarnes yeah, the first line of the array has header information like site id, sitename, latitude, longitude etc

Comment: it looks like you meant  new WeatherStation(split[0], split[1], Double.parseDouble(split2]), Double.parseDouble(split[3])); use split instead of line.

Comment: @isaace it's a comma delimited string and i tried to split it using String [] split = line[i].split(",");

Comment: @Ash which means that now the split values are in the split variable so you need to use split to get those values. You declared an array called split and in that array you are storing the values of "line" with each comma a new position in the array.

Comment: Can you print out the size of the line[] array, could you provide the first few lines in that array as well.

Comment: The issue is that you start your for loop at 1 rather 0. I know this to be the issue because if the for-loop had run even once, your list will not have size 0. It also suggests that `WeatherData.getData` either returns a single line or nothing, which means that if you were expecting a size of `136`, you need to make sure that the jar you have is functioning correctly

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to check the length of the line array which is read from the file

```
String line[] = WeatherData.getData();
System.out.println("Number of lines : " + line.length);
```

This way you will know if the file is being read correctly.
Can you also check this line

```
 WeatherStation z = new WeatherStation(line[0], line[1], Double.parseDouble(line[2]), Double.parseDouble(line[3]));
```

I think it should be

```
WeatherStation z = new WeatherStation(split[0], split[1], Double.parseDouble(split[2]), Double.parseDouble(split[3]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 String line[] = WeatherData.getData();
```

Are you sure `WeatherData.getData();` returning something ? and there exits `","`in the String which it is returning.And Kindly tell about the jar you importing so that i can correct if problem not solves.
I think you are not clear what you are doing.